# Is it possible to decode an AES encrypted video with node-webkit file on the fly?

Tags: node.js, encryption, html5-video, aes, node-webkit

With [file-encryptor](https://github.com/onmodulus/file-encryptor) and [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) its simple to encrypt a local videofile (webm) to a local encrypted file like `myvideo.dat`.

But is there a way to decrypt and view this video? Without a temp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file-encryptor encrypts all the webm container, you should encrypt the video stream like the [webM Encryption RFC](http://wiki.webmproject.org/encryption/webm-encryption-rfc). You could use the webm_crypt tool from the repository https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/webm-tools/.

For example:

```
$ webm_crypt -i video.webm -o encrypted_video.webm
```

This will generate a key file named vid_base_secret.key

```
$ webm_crypt -i video.webm -o encrypted_video.webm -video_options base_file=vid_base_secret.key
```

In the wiki of WebM project You can find more information although it is something relatively new.

Comment: Thanks @sinkmanu, do you know how to get Clear Key (key id and key) from this to be able to play using Clear Key for Shaka player?